# Android asynctask show progress dialog until function has finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know this answer has already been answered multiple times but I cannot get it to work properly. It's starts with activity A where a user needs to login via the function authenticate. When the user hits the button login I want the progressdialog to appear until the function authenticate has got a response. While success you go to another activity where you can navigate through the app.. Anyway sometimes when the internet is slow or if you're on mobile internet I still see activity A for a few seconds doing nothing while the auth function is going on. When it's done the system hops to activity B.

I tried using sleep thread thingy but that's not the point.. I want the progressdialog to appear when the user hits login and dissapear when the auth function has been finished.

With the help of AsyncTask I sometimes see the dialog for one flash of a second but not how it should be.. I also want to use asynctask for loading my listviews but the dialog isn't doing what it should.

Here my AsyncTask code

```
public class HeavyWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Context, Void> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

public HeavyWorker() {
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(AuthenticationActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Gettting data");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        authenticate(username, password, autoLogin);

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

And where I call the asynctask

```
builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_authenticate)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setView(viewInflater)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_button_login,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                EditText ETusername = (EditText) viewInflater.findViewById(R.id.username);
                                EditText ETpassword = (EditText) viewInflater.findViewById(R.id.password);

                                CheckBox optionAutoLogin = (CheckBox) viewInflater
                                        .findViewById(R.id.autoLogin);

                                checkAutoLogin = 0;
                                if (optionAutoLogin.isChecked()) checkAutoLogin = 1;
                                username = ETusername.getText().toString();
                                password = ETpassword.getText().toString();

                                new HeavyWorker().execute();
                                //authenticate(ETusername.getText().toString(), ETpassword.getText().toString(), checkAutoLogin);
                            }
                        })
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: where you are calling HeavyWorker in activity?

Comment: I guess the `authenticate` method is non-blocking? If so, the `AsyncTask` will immediately return and you only see the flash of the `ProgressDialog`

Comment: onClickListener from a button in a custom dialog.
What do you mean with non-blocking?

Comment: I mean it performs the authentication asynchronously? If so, the program execution is not waiting for the method to finish and returns from the `doInBackground`

Comment: Either that, or the authenticate is just returning very fast, you could try inserting a Thread.sleep inside doInBackground, simply to see the ProgressDialog

Comment: super-qua: I don't understand what you mean but it's just a normal function that sends a json request. No await function or anything just standard.

Comment: Usually network operations run in background, which means you don't receive any success or failure when calling the method, but when it is finished it calls a callback method with the result if the authentication. If that's the case, that is called non-blocking, since the program executions continues and receives the result at some (unspecified) point in time. Try putting a `Thread.sleep()` in your `doInBackground()` as @cYrixmorten suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you finishing the activity A when authentication success? In that case, you could skip onPostExecute

Comment: Yes activity B gets active when authentication is success. The new intent function is also called in the authenticate function.

Comment: This actually works until you press the back key on activity B and goes again to activity A and the dialog is still active.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, are you calling ActivityA.finish() when authentication is success? In that case, you don't need call dialog.dismiss(), because when Activity A "die", dialog will "die" too

Comment: Ok, that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) gives you quite a good example: You can post the Progress in the `onProgressUpdate(...)` And can update it from `doInBackground`  via  `publishProgress(int i)`

```
   private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         //DO YOUR PROGRESSBAR THINGS HERE
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: `dialog.setIndeterminate(true); `

Comment: Do you mean showing the dialog in onProgressUpdate? That doesn't work.